# Led not working on Android using Unified Push Notification of worklight (6.0.0.2)

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using the UPN system of Worklight Consumer Edition 6.0.0.2 to send push notifications.

When I receive a push notification no led light appears on Android. Why?
I tried on:

- a Samsung S4 with Android 4.3;
- a Nexus 5 with Android 4.4;
- a Samsung S3 mini with Android 4.1.2 .

I use WL.Server.createDefaultNotification to build the notification payload:

```
var notificationObj = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notification.TITLE, badge,{});
notificationObj.GCM.sound="default";
```

and then I use notifyAllDevices to push:

```
WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, notificationObj);
```

I have the app closed and the screen is switched off.
The result is: I receive the push notification successfully and a sound is played, but no led at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Notification priority API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#Priority) as provided by Android to allow for [pulsing the notification LED](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) (starting Android 4.1 "Jelly Bean" and above), is not available in Worklight.

If you'd like Worklight product designers to evaluate adding it to a future release, consider [submitting a feature request](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/connect.html).

AFAIK there is no way for a developer to extend support for this API in the application code, so there is no workaround.