# Default push notification sound in Worklight 6.1

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using Worklight Push Notification but on Android the push comes with no sound. I want to enable default sound (and LED if possible).

I'm using the sample push notification example code.

```
var notification = WL.Server.createDefaultNotification(notificationText, badgeDigit, {custom:"data"});
```

I also tried to assigning a value like `notification.GCM.sound = "true"` or `notification.GCM.sound = "default"` but it is playing continuous sound on some devices.

Comment: Do you want to add your own custom sound?

Comment: I want to use the default notification sound which is different from mobile to another. Just like what native apps do.

Comment: check the answer I posted and let me know if it helps.

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you will have to modify your app. Worklight will generate a skeleton class in your Android project, GCMIntentService.java

In order to add sound and flash the LED notification light, you will have to override the notify methods in the GCMIntentService class. Your file will look like this:

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;

public class GCMIntentService extends
    com.worklight.androidgap.push.GCMIntentService {
  @Override
  public void notify(Context context, String alert, int badge, String sound,
      Intent intent) {
    super.notify(context, alert, badge, sound, intent);

    // call helper method
    notifyLightAndSound(context);
  }

  @Override
  public void notify(Context context, String tickerText) {
    super.notify(context, tickerText);

    // call helper method
    notifyLightAndSound(context);

  }

  private void notifyLightAndSound(Context context) {

    // Get the default notification sound
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager
        .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    // build a notification with the light and sound
    // LED will be on for 1000 ms and off for 800 ms until you turn on your
    // screen
    Notification n = new Notification.Builder(context)
        .setLights(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS, 1000, 800)
        .setSound(notification).build();

    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    // play sound and flash LED
    mNotificationManager.notify(4, n);

  }
}
```

This will flash the LED and play the default notification sound of your phone "different based on each phone".

I hope this helps to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

- LED notification is not available.
  See here: [Led not working on Android using Unified Push Notification of worklight (6.0.0.2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831837/led-not-working-on-android-using-unified-push-notification-of-worklight-6-0-0-2)
- To use a custom notification sound (see [supported media formats](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)):

  1. If the folder does not exist already, add a folder named `raw` under the existing `native\res` folder in `yourProject\apps\yourApp\android\native`
  2. Place the sound file in the `raw` folder
- To use default notification sound, try sending it empty:

  ```
  notification.GCM.sound = "";
  ```

Comment: I tried it empty but it kept the notification silent.

Comment: So another solution is to download the default sound file and add it as a custom sound file. :)